How do I get rid of unwanted screen artifacts on iOS?
On my iOS application, there are 2 similar pages that have strange screen artifacts that pop up on the navbar. Below I have attached an image illustrating what I am talking about.
View Image Here
this seems to only happen after the screen orientation has been changed
[Edit] I should also point out that I am using Prism MAUI and not the maui shell for navigation. Sorry for not mentioning this.
I tried forcing the page to use the safe area of the iOS device in an attempt to avoid using the rounded device corners with the following code, but no luck
content page code:
<ContentPage
  xmlns:ios="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Maui.Controls.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific;assembly=Microsoft.Maui.Controls"
ios:Page.UseSafeArea="True"
>
</ContentPage>

I also added the following line to the constructer on the page's view class:
        public SignoffPage1(SignoffPage1VeiwModel vm)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //....

            BindingContext = vm;
#if IOS
            On<IOS>().SetUseSafeArea(true);
#endif
        }

This did not seem to work either.
Honestly, I have no idea what to do other than this. Any pointers on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Do you use shell tab (bottom or top tab) or tabbed page? Could you include more relevant code about how to reproduce it?

I apologize for the late post, but I figured this out. In my case, what I had to do was simply add the status bar behavior XAML object to each signature page's status bar behaviors property like so:
<ContentPage.Behaviors><views:StatusBarBehavior StatusBarColor="#4085c0" StatusBarStyle="LightStyle" /></ContentPage.Behaviors>

this then worked for me. I have this added on all the pages of the application already.
However, a quick tip, if you are using the prism library's navigation, and navigating to the very first page of your application, DO NOT PUT THIS THERE. it will cause problems since this library still has some issues with iOS.
